# Deploying asp.net website with SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deployment

I read some articles on how can I publish my website, but it is not clear to me considering my requirements.

I have to deploy my website on a personal computer (the website should be accessible only from that PC). And that computer has nothing installed as of now. So I want to ask what software needs to be installed? And how to actually deploy it?

Also I have to deploy the website along with my database as well. So can you please mention requirements for that too.

Comment: please explain which framework you are using , and specify your problem ..whether you want to build exe file(deskop application) or deploy project on web?

Comment: I developed the website in visual studio 2010 and sql server 2012. and i have to deploy project on PC (Its a website).

Comment: Ok..you need to just install visual studio and sql server (db) in your local machine..just publish your copy and run in your browser..but This is not proper way to access your project...Please deploy it in host(domain) otherwise for local machine just build desktop application(windows foem application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run your application from a remote computer, you need to publish it and you need to import it  from your PC's iismanager(inetmgr).

Refer the following articles - **How to deploy it?**
1. To [publish the application to create an artifact - ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. [Import a published web application - iis](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager)

**what software needs to be installed?**

1) In order to run your application in your pc you do not need to have a visual studio.  Our production servers do not have one but the website is up. 
2) You need to have **.net framework,iis manager and msdeploy** (to import your artifact).  You can have **sql server** installed in your local if you have your own data.  You need to *change the connection string before you run your web application* if you need to access your own database. Or you can point to the remote computer with proper connection strings.

Just follow these steps. The two links will give you more idea on publishing and accessing. Normally, you can create a zip file through web deploy.

> [I hope this is helpful.  Please mark it as answer if it helps you.]